# How to get an element front under the positioned as absolute block

Tags: css, sass

Question looks confusing but I'll break it down as much as possible.

I have swiper slider and I want to show some extra texts on the screen. To do so I created a `position:absolute` block which has transparent background and some text.

It pretty works, exactly what I wanted it but this time I can't use navigation arrows. Even if I give `z-index:9999` to them.

part of codes

navigation arrows

```
[class^=swiper-button]
  z-index: 9999 !important
  color: $color-white
```

absolute block

```
&__main
  padding: 0 $layout-horizontal-padding
  position: absolute
  z-index: 1
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  justify-content: flex-end
  top: 0
  left: 0
  right: 0
  bottom: 0
```

Comment: `z-index` works with positions other than `static`, try adding `position: relative` to your `[class^=swiper-button]`

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaAkbar they must be absolute

Comment: What must be absolute? Navigation arrows? Then why the code you shared doesn't have `position: absolute` on them like you have on your absolute block?

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaAkbar as I said I'm using plugin called swiper, slider related css comes with the plugin.

Comment: You've been here long enough to know a [mcve] is needed, so we can actually see it doesn't work.

Comment: @Ason swiper is one of the most knowns plugin. I don't think pasting whole source code of a popular open source plugin here is what they called minimal;

Comment: True -- and that is not what a _mcve_ is either. It is minimal part of that source code, so we can see which styles are applied to which html elements and by that be able to solve your problem. And even if you use a known plugin, no one here knows what style you might have applied, that break its normal behavior, hence the need to show us what part is not working.

Comment: Btw, in most cases where the `z-index` doesn't work, is when used on elements having `static` position or on a child where its parents siblings override it. And again, no such info is available in your question, e.g. your added extra text elements.

Comment: @Ason, you might be right. I'm here for some years but still don't know how to ask properly. Even if I provide the exact code the what question needed, people criticize blindly, actually not just for me. I see it happens all the time here. it makes me think twice whether I provide the code of a open source project or not. Btw below question actually worked, when I removed the pointer events.  Not sure the right answer but its fine for me

Comment: If the given answer solves your issue, it is clear your arrows are behind the text block. It also mean that you might further down the line will run into other problems, hence those kind of quick fixes is the worst solutions to a problem. Much better to learn to do things the proper way. Also be aware of browser support when it comes to `pointer-events`

Comment: @Ason you are right, thanks for your guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, I would say the issue is your `&__main` div is above your arrows causing it to catch the click events before they reach to the arrow buttons.

Try `pointer-events: none` on the `&__main` element.

Comment: I just tried and it works like a charm.. I appreciate it